# Interpret the logistic regression coefficient.

Tags: statistics, logistic-regression

I am running a logistic regression model in r to study the link between customer procrastination and whether customers repurchased. The dependent variable is whether customers will repurchase the item. The coefficient of **customer procrastination** is **-0.036** and the odds ratio is **exp(-0.036)=0.965**, which is less than 1. How can I interpret it appropriately? The longer procrastination customers are experiencing, the less chance they will repurchase it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes - the negative sign of the coefficient and the odds ratio less than $1$  indicates the odds (and so the probability) tends to decrease as the independent variable increases.  No surprise there.  At first sight the effect looks small, but that depends on the units you are using to measure procrastination

Comment: Thanks for your comments and it helps a lot.